# Sitecore 9.1 Distributed Install Fails on Database Deploy

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am executing a `Sitecore 9.1 Distributed Installation` but it is failing when `xConnectCollection` attempts to web deploy databases. I created a SQL Server account with `sysadm` rights and the SQL Server 2017 is in mixed mode.

Per previous guidance, I use a dedicated server (distributor) to deploy and each target has `WinRM` over `HTTPS` with the certificate of the distributor installed on each target.

Do I need to install the machine certs of each machine on each other and create listeners for each?

In an `SC 9.0 build`, the servers had no issues using Web Deploy to install the databases.

```
[--------------------------------------------------------- InstallWDP : WebDeploy ----------------------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Info: Adding MsDeploy.Site (MsDeploy.Site).
Info: Adding database (user id=mysqlaccount;data source=mySQL2017.Sitecore.local;initial catalog=sc910xp1_MarketingAutomation)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Deploying package to database: Pending.
Info: Creating deployment plan: Running.
Info: Initializing deployment (Start)
Info: Initializing deployment (Failed)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Deploying package to database: Faulted.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
At C:\resourcefiles\XP1-Distributed-RS.ps1:219 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @DistributedDeploymentParams -Verbose * ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:03:32
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-InstallSitecoreConfigurationTask.ps1:15 
char:9
+         Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ArgumentList $Configuration ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit late, but I ran into this today and found a resolution.

I found the error details in the event viewer under `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\WebDeploy\Errors`.

I had looked before under `Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft Web Deploy` which was empty.

In my case, the issue was the database server name.  It needs to be a name that is accessible from the `Web server (IIS)`, not the `distributor` server.  I had set up a host file entry on the distributor but not the webserver.